# Changing Character-Casing of URL's?

Tags: php, html, file, cpanel

I like to capitalize words where ever necessary. And I also prefer to capitalize the names of web pages, query strings etc etc.

All our url's look like this:

```
etc.com/Index.php
```

and

```
etc.com/Products.php?Category=CategoryName&SortBy=Date
```

But, I always get a Page Not Found error message if even just one of the character casing in the page name in the url isn't the same as the file name.

We've had quite a few complaints about this too! Some customers prefer to type the full URL - but often forget the casing that is used. Because they're used to websites that use all lowercase characters in URLs.

Normally I'd just change the filenames so they're all lowercase...

Is it at all possible - maybe using some settings in the server or cpanel or something to make it so all URL's are case-*in*sensitive?

Comment: This *really* is more of a server issue than a programming issue.

Comment: Lol, but... I don't know how to *programatically* change the casing thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mod_spelling.c` It's an Apache module that can handle your problem, so basically you need to enter into your `.htaccess` file

```
CheckSpelling on|off
```

And make sure that this module is loaded.

You can find more info here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_speling.html

Comment: So all I have to do is create a .htaccess file, upload it to root dir, with the following line: "CheckSpelling Off" (without quotes)?

Comment: *The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.* - I'll check to make sure the module's loaded now - Didn't see that comment.

Comment: I'm lookin in CPanel and it lets me search/browse available modules, but mod_speling or CheckSpeling isn't there. And I can't install it either because it just says the module isnt there.

Comment: This module comes with the apache distribution, so contact your support and tell them to include it for your web hosting, if you are administrator then uncoment line in http.conf